# Keras model does not construct the layers in sequence

Tags: deep-learning, keras, tensorflow

Every time I print the model summary it prints out the convlstm first and then batchnormalization at the end.

Here is the output of `model.summary`

```
|¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯|
| conv_lstm2d (ConvLSTM2D)  multiple                  416256    |
|                                                               |
| conv_lstm2d_1 (ConvLSTM2D)  multiple                295168    |
|                                                               |
| conv_lstm2d_2 (ConvLSTM2D)  multiple                33024     |
|                                                               |
| batch_normalization (BatchN  multiple               256       |
| ormalization)                                                 |
|                                                               |
| batch_normalization_1 (Batc  multiple               256       |
| hNormalization)                                               |
|_______________________________________________________________|
```

I want the batch_normalization layer after every conv_lstm2d except for the last layer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're seeing this issue: [BUG!! tf.keras.model.summary() output is wrong](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/44591). When you use the subclass API, the summary() method prints the layers in the order they are created, not the order they appear in the network. If you plot the network using the plot_model utility, this should output the layers in the correct order (output goes to a png file).

Comment: Aren't the batch norm layers created before the conv layers too though? they are interleaved both during creation and when applying it..